# Specified cast is not valid – SQL float to C# double

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

In my c# code, I have a double that I am trying to set to the value that is in my SQL Management 2008 R2 database that is of type float (which corresponds to a double in c#, right?). When I use this syntax

```
double x = (double)reader["column1"]; //reader is SqlDataReader object
```

I get the error "specified cast is not valid."

What gives?

Comment: If it's `float`, did you try casting to `float`?!!!

Comment: It's a double--it's unusual, but float in SQL corresponds to double in c#.

Comment: No, he's right it is a double, but only if it's not null. My personal preferred syntax is: double x = reader["column1"] as double? ?? 0.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using the helper classes available through the SqlDataReader object...

```
double dbl = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("DoubleColumn"));
```

If there is a chance the column could be null, you should account for that...

```
double dbl = (reader["DoubleColumn"] != DBNull.Value ? dr.GetDouble(dr.GetOrdinal("DoubleColumn")) : 0.0);
```

Comment: Thanks. This checks for null and if so sets the value to 0, which is what I need.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply [`GetDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdouble.aspx) directly:

```
reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("column1"))
```

Comment: also make sure you call IsDBNull to check for null values before calling this method.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Convert.ToDouble` method:

```
double x = Convert.ToDouble(reader["column1"]);
```

Comment: the best, Thanks